# How do I obtain a single array from all possible combinations of the elements of two vectors?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two vectors:

```
 x = [1 2 3]; y = [4 5]
```

I need a single array yx that gives me one-to-one combinations of the elements of both vectors. This is the code I have tried so far using of the examples from Stackoverflow.

```
sets  = {y, x};
[y x] = ndgrid(sets{:});
yx    = [y x]'
```

This gives me the result:

```
yx =

 4     5
 4     5
 4     5
 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
```

Whereas, I am expecting the following result:

```
yx =

 4     1
 4     2
 4     3
 5     1
 5     2
 5     3
```

Please, what am I doing wrong here? Any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to obtain is a *cartesian product* of the two vector.
Here's a solution:

```
>> x = [1 2 3]; y = [4 5];

>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(y,x);

>> result = [X(:) Y(:)]
result =

   4   1
   4   2
   4   3
   5   1
   5   2
   5   3
```

(this works also in Octave and does not require extra libraries)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. It all did work and i really do appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Your final `cat` is wrong. You expect that `x` and `y` are column vectors but they are 2x3-matrices. To get a 2-column matrix of all pairs, you need to linearize first:

```
yx    = [y(:) x(:)]
```

It outputs the data in a different order. If you want the same order, transpose `x` and `y` before vectorizing and concatenating.

Comment: Did you try this ?

Comment: Actually this is working, but outputs the data in a different order. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `combvec(x, y)`

```
>> x = [1 2 3]
x =
     1     2     3
>> y = [4 5]
y =
     4     5
>> combvec(x, y)
ans =
     1     2     3     1     2     3
     4     4     4     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with no complicated functions.

```
x = [1 2 3];
y = [4 5];
nx = numel(x);
ny = numel(y);

xy = [reshape(repmat(y,nx,1), 1, [])', repmat(x',ny,1)];

% xy =  [4     1
%        4     2
%        4     3
%        5     1
%        5     2
%        5     3
```

Explanation:

- We know that the output will have `x` repeated for each element in `y`, named `ny`.
- We know that the output will have each element of `y` repeated for each element in `x`, `nx`
- `repmat` repeats `x` simply for the second column.
- `repmat` used with `reshape` to "interweave" `y` with its repeated self to get the repeated digits in the `y` vector as the first column.

You could condense the code by not using `nx` and `ny`.

```
xy = [reshape(repmat(y,numel(x),1), 1, [])', repmat(x',numel(y),1)];
```